# Unable to test persistent sessions in Django 1.1

Tags: python, django

As part of the registration process for my site I have several views that set session data. Later views depend on the session data being set. This all works fine in the browser, however when I try to test it the session data seems to be lost in between requests which makes it impossible to test. Here's a simple example of the problem I'm having. I would expect get_name to have access to session['name'] and return a 200, however the session data is being lost and get_name returns a 302.

```
>>> c = Client()
>>> r = c.post(reverse(set_name))
>>> r = c.post(reverse(get_name))
>>> r.status_code
200

def set_name(request):  
    request.session['name'] = 'name'
    return HttpResponse()

def get_name(request):
    try:
        name = request.session['name']
    except KeyError:
        return redirect(reverse(set_name))
    return HttpResponse(name)
```

Comment: What settings apply in your test environment?  Is the settings middleware enabled correctly?  Are you logging in correctly in your unit test?  Are you tests running in the correct order?

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are tested quite awkwardly in Django. You have to setup the session engine first.

```
class TestSession(TestCase):
"""A class for working with sessions - working.

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/5278e2f2b9e6da13?pli=1

To modify the session in the client do:
session = self.client.session
session['key'] = 'value'
session.save()
"""

def setUp(self):
    """Do the session preparation magic here"""
    super(TestSession, self).setUp()

    from django.conf import settings
    from django.utils.importlib import import_module
    engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
    store = engine.SessionStore()
    store.save()  # we need to make load() work, or the cookie is worthless
    self.client.cookies[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME] = store.session_key
```

Use this class as a base class for your test cases. Check out the link for more info.

Comment: Ticket #10899 raises hope that this will be easier in future versions of Django. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10899